# Azure WebJobs Supported .Net Framework Version?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-webjobs

I have two separate Azure Web Apps which each have a continuous webjob running. After upgrading the C# projects to 4.6.1 I Published the Sites to Azure and they continued to work as did the webjobs.

I noticed that the configs had a different httpRuntime version to debug version below so I changed them from

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxRequestLength="30720" />
...
 </system.web>
```

to

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="30720" />
...
 </system.web>
```

After publishing the webapps and respective webjobs they still worked.

However after changing the webjobs app config's from

```
   <configuration>
     <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
     </startup>
    </configuration>
```

to

```
  <configuration>
     <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
     </startup>
    </configuration>
```

both webjobs revert to pending start status every time I republish or stop and start. The logs show error

```
[02/12/2016 19:48:35 > 686340: SYS INFO] Detected WebJob file/s were updated, refreshing WebJob
[02/12/2016 19:48:35 > 686340: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[02/12/2016 19:48:35 > 686340: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[02/12/2016 19:48:35 > 686340: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[02/12/2016 19:48:35 > 686340: SYS INFO] Run script 'Timbo.Azure.Worker.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[02/12/2016 19:48:35 > 686340: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[02/12/2016 19:48:35 > 686340: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -2146232576
[02/12/2016 19:48:35 > 686340: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
[02/12/2016 19:48:35 > 686340: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
[02/12/2016 19:49:36 > 686340: SYS INFO] Run script 'Timbo.Azure.Worker.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[02/12/2016 19:49:36 > 686340: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[02/12/2016 19:49:36 > 686340: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -2146232576
[02/12/2016 19:49:36 > 686340: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
[02/12/2016 19:49:36 > 686340: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
```

The error code **-2146232576** is spectacularly unhelpful particularly since I was unable to find anything on google or here to look it up against.

Reverting this setting and all works again. So my question is why does this happen, and why does a webjob which runs locally (development machine) with this setting work, but not on azure within a website whose framework setting (in appsettings) shows .Net version 4.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE: 4.6.1 is now deployed**

4.6.1 is not yet supported on the web app vms:

[Microsoft connect issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/11070060-webjobs-executables-fail-when-targeting-net-4-6-1)

[Git hub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/616)

Comment: But it's coming soon! :) Give it another week or so.

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: Yes, 4.6.1 is now deployed.